# How to show the top user list and current log in user position

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables

```
**Posts:**
| id | userID | title |

| 1  |    6   | text1 |
| 2  |    5   | text2 |
| 3  |    8   | text3 |


**Votes:**
    | id | userID | postID |

    | 1  |    6   |   2    |
    | 2  |    5   |   2    |
    | 3  |    8   |   1    |
    | 4  |    8   |   3    |
    | 5  |    8   |   2    |



**Sql**

SELECT p.*,(SELECT count(*) FROM votes AS v WHERE v.postID=p.id AS count)
FROM posts AS p WHERE p.userID = 6
ORDRER BY count DESC
```

This will make a top 3 list ,but I want on top if the list to have something like

```
Your position is 3
```

If the user is log in.How to calculate the user posittion? Base on how many votes his posts have

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
Select rank, temp_p.userID from
(
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, userId, count(1) as count
from
 (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, 
 votes v 
 inner join posts p on (v.postID=p.id)

 ) temp_p
ORDER BY temp_p.count DESC 
WHERE temp_p.userID.userID = 6
```

Comment: for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY count DESC) as temp_p WHERE p.iduser = 39 ' at line 13

Comment: again mistake on the same line

Comment: the word order is misspelled in the query, plz correct that n run

Comment: WHERE temp_p.userID.userid = 6' on line 19